# extending an integral domain by an integral element

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $A$ be an integrally closed integral domain, let $K$ be its field of fractions and $\bar{K}$ the algebraic closure of $K$. Let $t \in \bar{K}$ be integral over $A$. By a known theorem, the minimal polynomial $m_t(x)$ of $t$ over $K$ will have its coefficients in $A$.

I want to prove that $A[t] \cong A[x]/(m_t(x))$. Attempt: the map $A[x] \rightarrow A[t]$ is surjective. Take $p(x)$ inside the kernel. Then $p(t)=0$. Now $p(x) \in K[t]$ and so $m_t(x)$ must divide $p(x)$. Thus $p(x) = q(x) m_t(x)$ with $q(x) \in K[x]$. The proof will be complete once i show that $q(x) \in A[x]$, since then we will have that $p(x)$ is inside the ideal of $A$ generated by $m_t(x)$. What is the missing argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial $m_t(x)$ is a *monic* polynomial, hence polynomial long division of $p(x)$ by $m_t(x)$ produces only coefficients in $A$, hence $q(x) \in A[x]$.